# How do I display login message such as password expiry warning?

Tags: xubuntu, login, password, notification, active-directory

I'm using sssd to authenticate against an active directory. The passwords for the user may expire after a given time.

In `sssd.conf` you can set `[pam] pam_pwd_expiration_warning = X` to change the days a message appears prior password expiration. This works e.g. when using `sudo` or when logging in remotely via `ssh`.

Is there a way to display such a message (maybe as notification) after login?

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. And it would really help me to see this warning at a prominent position. And the best way IMO would be directly after graphical login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to create a script that works for exactly my problem. Thanks to @kos for the answer - it helped me to show the dialog itself.

I wrote the script based on [this solution](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060925114138223) but since `dscl` is not available for me I searched for another way to query the AD. [This blog entry](http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2006/11/17/querying-active-directory-with-unix-ldap-tools/) helped me to get started and find a solution to get exactly what I was looking for..

So here is my script which I then just trigger on session startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwPolicy=90
warnDays=10
user=`whoami`
userRecord=`ldapsearch -h mydomain.de -b 'dc=mydomain,dc=de' "(sAMAccountName=${user})" 2>/dev/null`
lastpwdMS=`grep -i pwdLastSet <<< "$userRecord" | sed 's/pwdLastSet: //'`
todayUnix=`date "+%s"`
lastpwdUnix=`expr $lastpwdMS / 10000000 - 11644473600`
diffUnix=`expr $todayUnix - $lastpwdUnix`
diffdays=`expr $diffUnix / 86400`
daysremaining=`expr $pwPolicy - $diffdays`

if [ "$daysremaining" -le ${warnDays} ]
then
  zenity --info --title="Password expiration" --text="The password for ${user} will expire in ${daysremaining} days."
fi
```

I'm not familiar with the AD but just try `ldapsearch -h mydomain.de -b 'dc=mydomain,dc=de' "(sAMAccountName=${user})" 2>/dev/null` if it works for you.

IMO this solution is neither pretty nor usable for other scenarios but it fixes this single problem. I'm still interested if anyone knows how to just show a dialog with the messages that would appear when logging in via ssh.

Comment: No problem. The hardest thing was to get some information out of the Active Directory ...

Answer (score 2):

I worked out a simple desktop app for my users in order to solve this issue. It is called ADpassword.

It checks (via kerberos tickets) password expiration date and shows a dialog when days left are under a configured threshold.

You can add it to user desktop start and run it everyday.

[ADpassword in Github](https://github.com/alfem/adpassword)